# Menu (JavaScript Isn't Being Accepted)

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

I have a menu for a game that I am making. It uses JavaScript to switch between the menu pages by changing the styles of the buttons and the display of the content. However, when I run it and click on any one of the three menu buttons nothing happens. It says the functions are not functions. It's probably a silly mistake but please help. Thanks for the help in advance.

Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
html, body {
background: linear-gradient(to bottom,#7EC0EE,#C1E5FF);
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
margin: 0;
}
#menu {
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);
font-family: Segoe UI;
background: #915921;
padding-left: 15px;
padding-top: 45px;
font-size: 17px;
position: fixed;
height: 50%;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#menubar {
background: transparent;
color: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
text-align: center;
line-height: 40px;
font-size: 20px;
position: fixed;
height: 40px;
width: 100%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#first {
transition: background 0.5s;
background: transparent;
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
width: 33%;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
}
#first:hover {
background: transparent;
}
#firstcontent {
display: block;
}
#second {
transition: background 0.5s;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
width: 33%;
left: 33%;
top: 0px;
}
#second:hover {
background: transparent;
}
#secondcontent {
display: none;
}
#third {
transition: background 0.5s;
background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
position: absolute;
height: 40px;
width: 34%;
left: 66%;
top: 0px;
}
#third:hover {
background: transparent;
}
#thirdcontent {
display: none;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="menu">
 <div id="menubar">
 <div id="first" onclick="first()">FIRST</div>
 <div id="second" onclick="second()">SECOND</div>
 <div id="third" onclick="third()">THIRD</div>
 </div>
 <div id="firstcontent">
 First
 </div>
 <div id="secondcontent">
 Second
 </div>
 <div id="thirdcontent">
 Third
 </div>
</div>

<script>
var first = document.getElementById("first");
var firstcontent = document.getElementById("firstcontent");
var second = document.getElementById("second");
var secondcontent = document.getElementById("secondcontent");
var third = document.getElementById("third");
var thirdcontent = document.getElementById("thirdcontent");

function first() {
first.style.background = "transparent";
firstcontent.style.display = "block";
second.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
secondcontent.style.display = "none";
third.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
thircontent.style.display = "none";
}

function second() {
first.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
firstcontent.style.display = "none";
second.style.background = "transparent";
secondcontent.style.display = "block";
third.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
thircontent.style.display = "none";
}

function third() {
first.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
firstcontent.style.display = "none";
second.style.background = "rgba(0,0,0,0.2)";
secondcontent.style.display = "none";
third.style.background = "transparent";
thircontent.style.display = "block";
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: may be due to you have named the function and variable the same. Like first() { } and first = somevalue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's may be because you have named the variable and function as same. Like first() { } and first = somevalue?

Answer (score 0):

Either rename your variables or rename your functions.  Having a variable and function with the same name just causes problems.